# Matplotlib plotting time versus concentration

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time, graph

I have my data in the following format in a csv file.

I have tried to write the code for this but it is not being converted into the proper format and hence i am getting error

18-10-2019 17:18,31.827753

18-10-2019 17:19,61.8619

18-10-2019 17:20,64.44997

18-10-2019 17:21,64.72129

18-10-2019 17:22,56.089733

How can i plot the time values against the concentration values in matplotlib?
Can anybody help me with the working code.

Comment: Can you please post your code? :)

Comment: I havent been able to come up with a valid code yet. It would be great if you can help.

Comment: I can mail you the csv files if required